# Chilkat error in QT (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, email, chilkat

I wanna send a simple email with Qt. I tried a lot of libraries but the one that I found the simplest was chilkat libraries. Here is my code...

```
CkMailMan mailman;

bool success = mailman.UnlockComponent("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    if (success != true) {
        qDebug() << mailman.lastErrorText() << "\r\n";
        return;
    }




mailman.put_SmtpHost("smtp.gmail.com");
mailman.put_SmtpUsername("xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com");
mailman.put_SmtpPassword("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");


CkEmail email;
QString body = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
QByteArray ba = body.toLatin1();
const char *c_str2 = ba.data();


email.put_Subject("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
email.put_Body(c_str2);
email.put_From("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

success = email.AddTo("xxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com");



success = mailman.SendEmail(email);
   if (success != true) {
       qDebug() << mailman.lastErrorText() << "\r\n";
       return;
   }

   success = mailman.CloseSmtpConnection();
      if (success != true) {
           qDebug() << "Connection to SMTP server not closed cleanly." << 
"\r\n";
       }

       qDebug() << "Mail Sent!" << "\r\n";
```

And here is the error...`error: cannot find -lChilkatDbg_x64d`

Edit:
.pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-05-20T16:57:12
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = WoW_Free_Gold
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp \



HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc



win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-
vc2017/libs/ -lChilkatDbg_x64
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/chilkat-9.5.0-
x86_64-vc2017/libs/ -lChilkatDbg_x64d
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc2017/libs/ -
lChilkatDbg_x64

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc2017/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc2017/include

DISTFILES += \
    chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc2017/libs/ChilkatDbg_x64.lib \
    chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc2017/libs/ChilkatDbgDll_x64.lib \
    chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc2017/libs/ChilkatRel_x64.lib \
    chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc2017/libs/ChilkatRelDll_x64.lib
```

How can I make this work ? 
Thanks all...

Comment: Show how you compile your project and your .pro file

Comment: https://pastebin.com/t2FcXeKG

Comment: Do not post a link, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44123064/edit) your question and add it

Comment: I just edited...

Comment: You could show the folder structure of your project.

Comment: Also you could tell us which version of Qt and Visual you have installed

Comment: 5.7 QT and 2010 Visual....  The structure is the same as a normal project except I added the .lib files in "Other files" but It gave the same error before I did...

Comment: Please show the structure of your folders or show an image of the folders.

Comment: Also you should download the library according to your version of visual, I see that you have downloaded the 2017 version but you use the visual 2010.

Comment: download here: https://chilkatdownload.com/9.5.0.67/chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc10-sp1.zip

Comment: I downloaded but still same error... http://imgur.com/a/whkge is the tree structure

Comment: In the image I do not see where the folder is chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-{version-of-visual}

Comment: Unzip the folder inside your project

Comment: and delete this: `DISTFILES += \
    chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc2017/libs/ChilkatDbg_x64.lib \
    chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc2017/libs/ChilkatDbgDll_x64.lib \
    chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc2017/libs/ChilkatRel_x64.lib \
    chilkat-9.5.0-x86_64-vc2017/libs/ChilkatRelDll_x64.lib`

Comment: Probably not the issue I used alot of libraries and I always imported them the same way...

Comment: But the library should be inside the folder since when you say $$PWD, this indicates the folder of the .pro file, and from there you are building the path, but in your case you do not find it since the folder does not exist.

Comment: I think that with other libraries you have added the path to the environment variables.

Comment: Have you tried decompressing the file inside your project?

Comment: Yea, no changes....

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're using MinGW, you would use one of the top 3 libs listed here:  https://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_mingw.asp

And for VC2010, you would choose either the 64-bit or 32-bit VC++ 10 libs at https://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_vcpp.asp#downloads

Comment: How am I supposed to build the .sh on windows ?